# Magnific Popup hides y-overflow of parrent window

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

The popup initiation hides vertical overflow of parrent window and therefore content of the parrent window jumps to right.
Is there a way to prevent it?

**Header:**

```
<link href="/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(\'.simple-ajax-popup\').magnificPopup({
            type: \'ajax\',
            overflowY: \'auto\',
            closeBtnInside: true,
            fixedContentPos: true,
            fixedBgPos: true,
            removalDelay: 200
        });
    });
```

**Content:**

```
<a href="popup.html" class="simple-ajax-popup">Get it</a>
```

**Footer:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

**This way:**

```
fixedContentPos: false
```

**is not good becouse it makes parrent window to scroll with popup scrolling.**

**UPD:**
I see the function there that should make right margin but it does not.

```
var s = mfp._getScrollbarSize();
windowStyles.marginRight = s;
windowStyles.overflow = 'hidden';

$('html').css(windowStyles);
```